# java equivalent for regex to replace all characters up to a specific character in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to find the java equivalent of doing the following string manipulation (vb.net):

```
   linkUrl = Regex.Replace(linkUrl, ".*url=", "")
```

Basically strip all characters up to and including the one provided. Also are there any known examples anyone can provide for similar regular expressions used in java.

Comment: [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
linkUrl = linkUrl.replaceAll(".*url=", "");
```

Comment: thanks. dumb me...I forgot about java case sensitivity and wondered why the error line was there.